# Python Tkinter: Color changing grid of buttons?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, grid

I understand that you can make a button that can do some actions when clicked with Tkinter, but how can I just make a button that turns from one color to another when clicked? Then, from that, how do I replicate that button to make a grid of them? I would also settle for a grid of buttons that just change from one character to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Tkinter

color="red"
default_color="white"

def main(n=10):
    window = Tkinter.Tk()
    last_clicked = [None]
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
            b = Tkinter.Button(window, bg=default_color, activebackground=default_color)
            b.grid(column=x, row=y)
            # creating the callback with "b" as the default parameter bellow "freezes" its value pointing
            # to the button created in each run of the loop.
            b["command"] = lambda b=b: click(b, last_clicked)
    return window

def click(button, last_clicked):
    if last_clicked[0]:
        last_clicked[0]["bg"] = default_color
        last_clicked[0]["activebackground"] = default_color
    button["bg"] = color
    button["activebackground"] = color
    last_clicked[0] = button

w = main()
Tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Is there any way to make the button stay active even after I've selected another button. What I really want is buttons that can be changed between two colors when I click them. If you can help, please try to just point me in the right direction rather than giving me the whole answer. I'm still learning and want to try some stuff on my own!