# How can I change color of button when it pushed with tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I made 100 buttons and I want to change color of button which pushed.
How can I do that?
Here is my code.

```
import tkinter as tk

def settingships():
    column = -1
    row = 0
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('set ships')
    root.geometry('470x310')
    for i in range(101):
        if i > 0:
            if i%10 == 1:
                row += 1 
                column = -1
            column += 1
            text=f'{i}'
            btn = tk.Button(root,text=text,command=collback(i)).grid(column=column,row=row)
    root.mainloop()


def collback(i):
    def nothing():
        btn.config(bg='#008000')

    return nothing
```

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is `callback`?

Comment: Read up on [function-callback-in-event-binding-w-and-w-o-parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421018)

Comment: This question already has answers here:[python-tkinter-color-changing-grid-of-buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241671)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `i` is not used in `collback()`.  Second `btn` is undefined in `nothing()`.  You should pass `btn` to `collback()` instead.

In order to do that you need to replace the following line:

```
btn = tk.Button(root,text=text,command=collback(i)).grid(column=column,row=row)
```

to:

```
btn = tk.Button(root, text=text)
btn.grid(column=column, row=row)
btn.config(command=collback(btn))
```

And modify `collback()` as below:

```
def collback(btn):
    def nothing():
        btn.config(bg='#008000')
    return nothing
```

Or simply use lambda to replace `collback()`:

```
btn.config(command=lambda b=btn: b.config(bg='#008000'))
```

Comment: Thank for your comment. It worked. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @IgorBond: If this answer helped you please don't forget to upvote and [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer so the post is marked as answered.